# PayPal PHP SDK, Getting the Payment Amount

Tags: php, api, paypal

I am using [PayPal PHP SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) for processing PayPal payments.

A user adds items to my cart and then chooses to pay via PayPal. I construct a Paypal [PAYMENT](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Payment.php), send the [PAYMENT](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Payment.php) to Paypal, the user logs in and approves the [PAYMENT](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Payment.php). The user is then redirected back to my website with the three `$_GET` parameters where I can then execute the [PAYMENT](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Payment.php).

All good so far.

According to the code, a [PAYMENT](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Payment.php) holds an array of [TRANSACTIONS](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Transaction.php). It seems each [TRANSACTION](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Transaction.php) holds an [AMOUNT](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Amount.php).

**My Question:** How do I retrieve what the user paid? If there are multiple [TRANSACTIONS](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Transaction.php) that can take place under one [PAYMENT](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Payment.php) - how do I know which [TRANSACTION'S](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Transaction.php) [AMOUNT](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Amount.php) to use?

(When I pass the initial [PAYMENT](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Payment.php) to PayPal for approval, I do only provide one [TRANSACTION](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Transaction.php), so I would assume when PayPal returns the approval back to my site, there will still be only one [TRANSACTION](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Transaction.php), however, I do not want to assume this will always be the case!)

Comment: If you are constructing the Paypal payments at this point you should know which amount your user is paying and you should only need the payment confirmation. Anyway this should rather be a question for the developers of this library right?

Comment: Yes, I do know the amount the user SHOULD be paying. What I am trying to do is validate the amount that I know they SHOULD be paying with the amount from the transaction the PayPal says they ACTUALLY paid. I don't think this is really a question for the developers of this particular library, ALL PayPal libraries will use an array of transactions (see how a payment is constructed from the PayPal developer docs: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment)